# Create a Kafka topic if it does not already exist with Python-kafka admin client?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

With Python-kafka admin client I know how to create and delete topics.

But is there any way to check if that topic exists or not? If not then only I wanted to create it.
How can I do that in python -kafka admin client?
I didnt see anything in the documentation.

Comment: you can use kafka script ? kafka-topic.sh --list

Comment: i need python script

Comment: Idk but you can probably call `kafka-topic.sh --list` from any python script and then parse the output. Or better use `kafkaConsumer.topics()` ref: https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.topics

Comment: I am not sure how to call  kafka-topic.sh --list in python script. Can you just tell me that?

Comment: In case someone want to use python to run:
- First you need to know location of `kafka-topic.sh`. 
- Second after that you can use python `os.system` or `subprocess` to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [KafkaConsumer object](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafkaconsumer) **without** specifying the optional input argument `topics` and then call the `.topics()` on the created object.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create topic that is already exist then Kafka admin client raise Exception **TopicAlreadyExistsError** so you can handle that exception in your code like I did...

Let me provide you the sample code I built for my use case

```
def create_topic(self, topic_name=None, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1):
    try:
        topic_list = []
        topic_list.append(NewTopic(name=topic_name, num_partitions=num_partitions, replication_factor=replication_factor))
        self.admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
        self.show_topic_on_console()
        return True
    except TopicAlreadyExistsError as err:
        print(f"Request for topic creation is failed as {topic_name} is already created due to {err}")
        return False
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Request for topic creation is failing due to {err}")
        return False
```

Alternative flow - you can design like below

1. Extract list of the topics
2. Check whether request topic in the list
   or not
3. If not in the list the create topic